# oracle sql Developer taking time to fetch all records

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

My query is giving output in less than a second for first 50 records in Oracle SQL Developer. When I select all(Ctrl + A) in Query result then it takes 120 second to fetch all records(165k). Could you please suggest me if there is any scope  to optimize this ?

Can you also explain how the query is working for first 50 records of result and then for rest of the records ? Is the SQL engine fetching the rest of records from the data blocks OR from the result cache ?

Many Thanks,
Asit

Comment: pls share the sql

Comment: "Could you please suggest me if there is any scope to optimize this ?" - Faster network, faster disk, faster and more RAM, ...

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of things that could be a factor here, the most obvious being what the records are. 165,000 records is not a ridiculously oversized ask, but how large is each individual record? Remember, these records must be read from the DB, pass through the network, and then be processed by SQL Developer itself.

When I've run into this problem, you can typically watch the sql developer process spike the CPU and RAM as it's trying to ingest all those records in whatever internal process it utilizes.

Comment: you have two things to wait on - the additional fetches required to get all those rows AND you have to wait for the GRID to initialize and populate with all the data. it's resource intensive as you can see...my question is usually, why do you REALLY need so many rows all at once to browse with human eyes? user a WHERE clause and keep your results to hundreds, not thousands or millions

Comment: @thatjeffsmith you're preaching to the choir. My guess is they may be trying to export to CSV or something.

Comment: there's no need to fetch all the records to the grid to do a simple export

Comment: @thatjeffsmith no, but I've seen people use that work flow before.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple query (something like `select * from some_table`), I presume every today's GUI does the same - fetches the first "n" (50, 100, 500) rows *fast*. It returns an unordered set and says "here you are, look at what you got".

But, if it goes slightly more complex, e.g. `select count(*) from some_table` or `select * From some_table order by col1`, then it has to fetch *all* rows, and for large tables it takes time.

Also, as queries go *wild* (joins, aggregations, whatnot), it also makes it more complex and more time consuming.

So - how much time would you consider *satisfying* for 165K rows? Ctrl + A *does* take time.

Answer (score 0):

SQL developer stops the execution as soon as it fetches first 50 records. However you can increase it upto 200.

In SQL Developer, Go to Preferences —> Database —> Advanced —> SQL Array Fetch Size (between 50 and 200) --> *Change the value to 200*

Comment: we don't stop execution, but we DO grab the records with a fetch, and the default is 50 rows at a time. If doing LOTS of records, it's better to increase the array size a bit..you're trading number of round trips for BIGGER payloads